html in vscode file path links and image links do not work
html code
Image of Issue
Image of Issue
I'm working on a udemy web development course and for all the mini-projects/assignments I do the file
path does not load or link to the desired file or image. I've tried looking it up and some sites say it maybe a security or certificate issue regarding visual studio or chrome itself. I'm at a complete loss as to how I should resolve this.
Image of Issue
Image of Issue
Here are some more images of the issue I've been facing.

for relative paths, don't use ./ in the path

why are you dealing with a file in a temp folder like that? did you properly unpack the zip file in a dedicated folder? does it contain the assets as those paths expect to?

First, get a real webserver to test e.g. XAMPP. That will resolve the issue if you reference root-relative pathes. Second, never run code within temporary files. If you want to code and save code locally then at least use a dedicated folder for it. Third, read [ask] and provide debugging details in the form of a [repro]. Images are neither acceptable nor suitable. It would have even been easier to use ctrl + a -> ctrl + c -> ctrl + v

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Remove the ./ from path link. That is used on powershell and linux only

Technical incorrect. ./ is a correct url path to select the current directory. Not something you only use on Linux or Powershell. Besides that, most web servers are Linux based.
